# here is a trick C# random class delima

Tags: c#

the question i am asking is what is the highest numeric value X will hold and what is the lowest in this code:
Random rand = new Random();
int x = 1 - rand.Next()%15;
I have entered this and receive a value of -12 as a result but cannot get a range.

Answer (score 0):

`rand.Next() % 15` will give you a number between 0 and 14. (If we assume that it generates only positive integers, otherwise you can use do it with a negative number too take a look here how : 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519845/modulo-of-a-negative-number

Then add the 1 - {a number from the set of 0 and 14} and you get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int x = 1 - rand.Next() % 15;
// x in range from -13 to 1
```

However pay attention that "rand.Next() % 15" is equal to "rand.Next(15)" and also you can use this code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int x = rand.Next (-13, 2);
// x in range from -13 to 1
```

rand.Next(minValue, maxValue) where minValue - inclusive, maxValue - exclusive